# Circuit containing only Hadamard gate returns bad results

Tags: hadamard, ibm-quantum-devices

[image]I am new to quantum computing. My circuit contains only one qubit, one Hadamard gate and an operation to measure the state of the qubit. So, as I understand, the qubit is in superposition state after doing through the H gate, and has a probability of 50% of being in both states 0 and 1. After I measure it, (as in we force it to get out of its wave-like state or superposition state),I always end up with an output of 1? Is not it supposed to be random (quantum randomness) ?

Comment: perhaps you could show your code? It's easier to help if we know exactly what you've tried to do!

Comment: actually its not a code but only a visualition of these quantum gates on the q-sphere. I added a picture. thank you for your help

Comment: What is the plus in a circle?

Comment: its for changing the phase and state of the qubit

Comment: Perhaps try first without those + operators. You can also try [quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22H%22],[%22Measure%22]],%22init%22:[0,1]}) to double check the results

Comment: okey thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact the in simulation a measurement gate really measures. In other words, the result is either 0 or 1. Try to remove measurement and you will see 50:50 states 0 and 1. Then try to run your circuit on simulator. The result should be also 50:50, or very close to this distribution.

Note that you do not have to reset the qubit. At the beginning it is always in state 0. Moreover, two $X$ gates cancel each other, so you can remove it. To change the phase of your state, use only one negation.

Comment: okey i understand thank you very muuch!!

Comment: @Wiss: you are welcome. Could you please accept my answer provided your problem is solved? Thanks.